# How to add value to input by clicking on another input

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with my project. What I am trying to do is basically an ATM. But I have a problem with adding a value to an input, by clicking on another input/button like in a real ATM. Can someone explain how it should be done?

Here is my code:

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>ATM</title>
</head>
<body>
Please enter your pin:
<form action="/script2.js" method="get">
   <input type="password" name="pin" pattern="[0-9]{4}" maxlength="4" id="pin" value="">
   <input type="button" value="1"  onclick="add(this.value)">
   <input type="submit" value="Validate">
</form>



<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html> ```

and JS: 

const pinPassword = document.getElementById('pin').value;

function add(x){
   pinPassword.value = x;
}
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 let pin = document.getElementById('pin');


        function add(x) {
            if (pin.value.length <= 3) {
                pin.value += x;
            }
        }
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ATM</title>
</head>

<body>
    Please enter your pin:
    <input type="password" name="pin" pattern="[0-9]{4}" maxlength="4" id="pin" value="">
    <input type="button" value="1" id="one" onclick="add(this.value)">


 
</body>

</html>
```

i come up with this, I'm just a beginner so i don't know if this is the best solution

Comment: Great job man. I was so close haha

Answer (score 1):

You need to get value from button and add in textbox.

```js
var textValue = '';
var err = document.getElementById('errMessage');
function add(value) {
    var txt = document.getElementById('pin');
    if(txt.value.length < 4)
    {
        textValue += value;
        txt.value = textValue;
    }
    
 }
```

```html
<input type="password" pattern="[0-9]{4}" maxlength="4" size="4" id="pin" value="" style="width: 200px">
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="1" onclick="add(this.value)">
<input type="button" value="2" onclick="add(this.value)">
<input type="button" value="3" onclick="add(this.value)">
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="4" onclick="add(this.value)">
<input type="button" value="5" onclick="add(this.value)">
<input type="button" value="6" onclick="add(this.value)">
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="7" onclick="add(this.value)">
<input type="button" value="8" onclick="add(this.value)">
<input type="button" value="9" onclick="add(this.value)">
<br><br>
<input style="margin-left: 30px" type="button" value="0" onclick="add(this.value)">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use addEventListenr on you `element` and get the value from `event`

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>ATM</title>
</head>
<body>
Please enter your pin:
<form action="/script2.js" method="get">
   <input type="password" name="pin" pattern="[0-9]{4}" maxlength="4" id="pin" value="">
   <input type="button" value="1">
   <input type="submit" value="Validate">
</form>



<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
    const inputOne = document.getElementById("one");
    const pinPassword = document.getElementById("pin");

    inputOne.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      pinPassword.value = e.target.value;
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: I got this. Unfortunately there is a new problem, that you can add more then 4 numbers that are restricted in password.

Comment: I mean form won't let you move foward, but you can add more then 4 characters in the input.

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej there is pattern="[0-9]{4}" maxlength="4" and its working if i type numbers from my keyboard

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej i see nice!

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is simply list this function and apply it on all your number buttons

```html
<form action="/script2.js" method="get">
   <input type="password" name="pin" pattern="[0-9]{4}" maxlength="4" id="pin" value="">
   <input class="input-button" type="button" value="1"/>
<input class="input-button" type="button" value="2"/>
<input class="input-button" type="button" value="3"/>
<input class="input-button" type="button" value="4"/>
<input class="input-button" type="button" value="5"/>
<input class="input-button" type="button" value="6"/>
<input class="input-button" type="button" value="7"/>
<input class="input-button" type="button" value="8"/>
<input class="input-button" type="button" value="9"/>
<input class="input-button" type="button" value="0"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Validate">
</form>
```

```js
const pinInputEl = document.getElementById('pin')
const buttonEls = document.querySelectorAll('.input-button') 

const touchToAdd = (buttonEl) => {
  buttonEl.addEventListener('click',()=> {
    pinPassword.value += e.target.value
  })
}

buttonEls.forEach(buttonEl => touchToAdd(buttonEl))
```